# Updating text in a HTML document with Bash

Tags: bash, linux, posix, sh

This is a small script to update my project's README file. Notes on improvements from any aspect are welcome!

Here is the [document it updates](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/T145/the-blacklist/master/.github/README.md).

**readme.sh** *(Executed like so: ./readme.sh)*

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en:el

set -eu

domain_linecount=$(cat black_domain.txt | wc -l)
ipv4_linecount=$(($(cat black_ipv4.txt | wc -l)-$domain_linecount))
ipv6_linecount=$(($(cat black_ipv6.txt | wc -l)-$domain_linecount))

domain_entries=$(printf "%'d" $domain_linecount)
domain_size=$(du -h black_domain.txt | gawk -F'\t' '{ print $1 }')

ipv4_entries=$(printf "%'d" $ipv4_linecount)
ipv4_size=$(du -h black_ipv4.txt | gawk -F'\t' '{ print $1 }')

ipv6_entries=$(printf "%'d" $ipv6_linecount)
ipv6_size=$(du -h black_ipv6.txt | gawk -F'\t' '{ print $1 }')

sed -i \
    -e "s/\(<td id=\"domain-entries\">\).*\(<\/td>\)/<td id=\"domain-entries\">$domain_entries<\/td>/g" \
    -e "s/\(<td id=\"domain-size\">\).*\(<\/td>\)/<td id=\"domain-size\">${domain_size}B<\/td>/g" \
    -e "s/\(<td id=\"ipv4-entries\">\).*\(<\/td>\)/<td id=\"ipv4-entries\">$ipv4_entries<\/td>/g" \
    -e "s/\(<td id=\"ipv4-size\">\).*\(<\/td>\)/<td id=\"ipv4-size\">${ipv4_size}B<\/td>/g" \
    -e "s/\(<td id=\"ipv6-entries\">\).*\(<\/td>\)/<td id=\"ipv6-entries\">$ipv6_entries<\/td>/g" \
    -e "s/\(<td id=\"ipv6-size\">\).*\(<\/td>\)/<td id=\"ipv6-size\">${ipv6_size}B<\/td>/g" ./.github/README.md
# xmlstarlet is probably better to handle this
```

Comment: It is great to see what you ended up with.  https://github.com/T145/the-blacklist/blob/master/scripts/update_readme.sh  You've integrated our feedback excellently.  Bravo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Good

- great variable names, but I quibble over a couple later on
- nice use of blank lines to organize code
- appropriate use of `sed`.  (Regex search and replace is the only time to use it.)  I wouldn't expect any XML tools to be an improvement. `:)`
- you're using a subset of [bash strict mode](http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/)
- using `env` for portability

## Questions

Some things I wish the code had comments for:

- Why do you need to set the `LANG*` variables?
- Why are you subtracting the `$domain_linecount` from the line count you got for that file?  (More on this in a later bullet.)
- Explaining what the code is for in one line near the top.  You included this in your code review, which is also required, but having it in the code is nice.

## Suggestions

- Your `du -h | gawk` is doing the same thing for just different filenames.  Put it in a function.
- I see from the table heading in your HTML that the line counts are unique values instead of just being a line count of that file.  Instead of documenting as I encouraged above, it might be better to rename these variables `ipv4_uniquelines` or something that conveys the uniqueness so the subtraction doesn't look so odd.
- try shellcheck
- The "useless use of cat" report is because people would really like you to write things like `wc -l filename`, but that changes the output of `wc` and some of us like to see things flow from left to right easier, so I really wouldn't change it.
- don't call it `readme.sh` because then github thinks it is a readme.  https://github.com/T145/the-blacklist/tree/master/scripts  `update_readme.sh` would be fabulous.

Comment: I export the variables at the top so `printf` can process the `"%'d"` expression, and print numbers with commas. I noticed inconsistent results just appending `LANG` to the `printf` statement in a script.

Comment: Certainly worth a comment in the code to explain that for future readers (I often find that a review keeps my code unchanged, but the comments greatly improved!)

Comment: No, the catless equivalent is `wc -l <filename` (and doesn't produce different output).  You can always write `<filename wc -l` if you really like left-to-right streaming, but I don't generally recommend that.

Answer (score 7):

Your code seems pretty much fine, and chicks has pointed out most of the issues I have. It's not a bad implementation of the approach you've chosen, but I have to wonder if that's the *right* approach.

HTML is a complex format, and while using regex to parse it can work as long as you've structured it in a consistent manner known in advance (which definitely seems to be the case here), couldn't it be easier to start from a template file, with easy-to-find indicators showing where to put data, and generating a new readme file by just replacing those indicators? That way, so long as the markers stay consistent it doesn't matter if the rest of the presentation is restructured, or even if you switch to an entirely different markup language, the script should continue working regardless, and you won't have to keep the script up to date as you change the text and markup around the data. It might be worth considering an approach where the last command looks more like

```
sed \
    -e "s/{{domain_entries}}/$domain_entries/g" \
    -e "s/{{domain_size}}/$domain_size/g" \
    -e "s/{{ipv4_entries}}/$ipv4_entries/g" \
    -e "s/{{ipv4_size}}/$ipv4_size/g" \
    -e "s/{{ipv6_entries}}/$ipv6_entries/g" \
    -e "s/{{ipv6_size}}/$ipv6_size/g" \
    scripts/README-template.md \
    > .github/README.md
```

Comment: I just don't like duplicating data where possible on principle. This was definitely a consideration. B/c I'd be changing the file and committing the changes on GH automatically anyway I just stuck w/ in-place changes.

Answer (score 6):

One thing you might choose to do, given the neat correspondence of variable names and element ids, is to generate the sed script from the list of variables:

```
# Produce a sed script that replaces TD elements' contents with value of
# same-named variable.
# Arguments: list of variable names
make_subst_script() {
    for i
    do
        printf 's/\(<td id="%s">\).*\(<\/td>\)/\\1%s\\2/\n' "${i//_/-}" "${!i}"
    done
}
```

The `${i//_/-}` expansion is needed, to change the `_` in variable names to the `-` used in the HTML `id` attributes.

(I also used back-references to shorten the substitution, and removed the `/g` modifier - put that back in if you really do have lines where you need to substitute more than once).

You can then invoke `sed` on the result:

```
sed -e "$(make_subst_script domain_entries domain_size ipv4_entries ipv4_size ipv6_entries ipv6_size)" \
    -i .github/README.md
```

It's easy to combine this technique with template markers as [recommended by Sara J](/a/262916/75307).

---

We can make it slightly more efficient by eliminating useless `cat`:

```
domain_linecount=$(wc -l <black_domain.txt)
```

And `cut` is simpler and lower-overhead than the `awk` interpreter:

```
ipv4_size=$(du -h black_ipv4.txt | cut -f1)
```

Alternatively, instead of `du` on a single file, we could use `stat`, but then we need to transform its output to give K/M/G/etc (but with a lot more flexibility):

```
ipv4_size=$(stat -c %s black_ipv4.txt | numfmt --to=iec)
```

As [chicks suggests](/a/262907/75307), we should make a function for this.

Comment: You're right that `g` mode is not needed. The variables and HTML `id`s do not have a 1-1 correspondence though. The HTML tags use a `-` as a delimiter.

Comment: Oh, you're right - we need to use `${!i//_/-}` expansion to convert from `_` to `-`.  Now fixed.